# Google App Script to Insert Gravity Forms Submissions into Google Sheets via WebHooks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks

I've set up the WebHooks in the backend of a WordPress site that I plan to use to send the Gravity Forms submissions in that WP site to my Google Sheet, with different form submissions being sent to different tabs of my Google Sheet.

I'd like to use Google Apps Script to get the WebHooks to post the form submissions to the tabs of my spreadsheet, unless there's a totally forever free (not free trial) add-on that's easy to use. From what I've researched I haven't found any such add-on, so I was hoping someone could help me with the GAS script as I'm on a time crunch.

Here's the Google Sheet I would like the form submissions to be inserted to:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I3pjRT_n6Np9ux-_blJnmZ8dxvXRg2zm-lWs3s_b4NY/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you!
Katie

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is deploying your script as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). This allows you to handle the methods doGet(e) and doPost(e) in your code. (Whatever variable is between the parentheses are your parameters).

To start you want to take your script and goto publish> Deploy As Web App. Change the access to Anyone, even anonymous. Then hit deploy.

The link provided after submission could then be used with the webhook. Going off of this [link](https://en.support.wordpress.com/webhooks/) under the Hook column is the name for the parameter you will be looking for. Still following the eample your code should look something like this.

```
function doPost(e)
{
  //gets the comment most recently posted.
  var comment = e.parameters.comment_content;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  sheet1.appendRow(comment);
}
```